# Wordpress - adding post category requires page refresh to show up

Tags: wordpress, asynchronous, refresh, categories

I have built a new theme on the latest version of Wordpress (Version 3.3.1 as of this post).

When adding a new category, (both in a regular post or custom post) the new category doesnt appear, I have to actually refresh the page in order for it to show up. If I am writing a new post that means I need to save / publish a post before I can refresh the page. This is a bit annoying as normally I am used to Wordpress adding the new category and updating the page asynchronously so I can then choose the new category straight away.

Has anyone had this happen to them before? I have kept my theme really light at the moment so not sure what could be causing it. Pretty much all my functions code is for the custom post types I have been making, but the issue is present for standard posts too.

Anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT** *FIXED*
I just needed to clean up my functions file by removing some whitespace

Comment: (6 years later and this post is still saving lives) - Same problem, you are right, this fixed my issue. To keyword this post up a bit I was searching google for "wordpress custom taxonomy add new ajax not working" "wordpress custom taxonomy add new broken" "wordpress custom taxonomy something went wrong error ajax" To fix the problem I removed all the whitespace from various PHP includes, in my case it was not functions.php it was a custom plugin that I had empty whitespace. seems any hook that uses add_action( 'init') needs careful consideration. your post here saved me a headache, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem, one of the main reasons stuff like this could go wrong is because of white space before and after the opening and closing PHP tags, respectively, in your functions.php file of your theme.

More information can be found in the [Wordpress FAQ and troubleshooting section](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F).

Comment: Crazy but true!

Comment: Yes, this worked for me - removing extra white space at the top of functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue today, and white space in PHP files was the problem.

However, **I want to share the steps I took to resolve the issue**:

1. I tried opening every PHP file and checking for blank lines at the start and end of the file. I picked up a few problems but the issue persisted.
2. I was also able to do a regex search in my IDE for problems. I used [Textmate/Regex: Strip whitespace from beginning/end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412690/textmate-regex-strip-whitespace-from-beginning-end-of-file) as a reference point and [without quotation marks] the following regex searches "\?>[\r\n\t ]+" to find space/blank lines at the end of a file, and "[\r\n\t ]+<\?" for the start of a file.
3. There were still problems so I narrowed down the scope by disabling plug-ins (I also knew it was one of my own plug-ins in the site I'm developing, so that made it easier).
4. Re-activating a plug-in give a warning "The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output during activation". This helped me in the trial-and-error process of narrowing down the source.
5. Once I had the plug-in identified, I started commenting out require_once() calls in PHP files until the "The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output" warning disappeared.
6. Eventually, I realised I'd broken the plug-in during refactoring and was doing a require_once() on a PHP file that was pure HTML (to inject favicon tags into a page header) rather than the appropriate add_action() call on the file as I originally intended.

Hopefully, these debug steps provide some inspiration to other people suffering the same problem. As far as I know, WordPress does not offer any easy way to identify the cause of this problem (i.e. it does not identify which file has bad spaces in it).